# Don't apply rewrite engine on subdomain...?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect my domain's url to **www** url with htaccess.

It works fine but problem is that it applies even on subdomain.

My subdomain is **adminpanel.mypage.com** but rewrite engine rewrites even subdomain to **www.adminpanel.mypage.com/adminpanel/**

which is strange and I didn't expect it to work that way. Any possible solution?

My code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

*rewrite engine is on already*

Comment: I would say this is expected behaviour as `adminpanel.mypage.com` is not starting with `www.`. If your host name is the same for all request try to compare if `%{HTTP_HOST}` starts with `mypage.com`.

Comment: How can I do it? I don't really know the htaccess syntax...

Comment: The guy below wrote exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `www` rule to make it specific to main domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mypage\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: It doesn't add the www in front of domain, though the subdomain is okay now.. Any reason/solution?

Comment: You need to change `RewriteCond` line and place your actual domain name without `www`

Comment: Yeh the problem was that the htaccess didnt upload properly on server. Your solution works, thanks